# psexec.exe prompt a "is not a valid win32 application" message after multiple executions

Tags: windows, cmd, psexec

i'm using `psexec.exe` from my CMD to access a remote machine.

everything worked fine for the first couple attempts,
but on the nth attempt (in my case the 5th attempt) i got the following error prompt message:
`is not a valid win32 application`

this is my command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder\psexec.exe" \\MY_REMOTE_IP -u MY_USERNAME -p MY_PASSWORD cmd
```

could it be a problem of too many open connections?
where can i see my open connections if any?
how can i properly close a remote connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i reinstall PSExec.exe and it solved the problem, not sure what cause the issue but it definitely solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that the psexec service is down in the target machine.

In my case it was down because drive C was out of storage. After I free some space in drive C, I had to restart the machines for the service to start again (I couldn’t start the psexec service manually)

Comment: thanks for replying, it didn't seems to be a problem of storage in my case, but maybe this solution will help others :)